# Check select for data output

Tags: php, laravel

There is a select that outputs data from tables. When creating a post, I need the data that he selected in select not to be repeated anymore, that is, for the second time he could not select the same values that he had already selected

**Select in create.blade**

```
            <select class="select-css" name="title" required="">
                <option selected="" value="" disabled="">Выберите сервер</option>

                @foreach($users as $user)
                    @foreach($user->guilds as $guild)
                        <option value="{{$guild->id}}">{{$guild->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

**CreateController**

```
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $users = User::with('guilds')->get();
        $categories = Category::all();
        $languages = Language::all();
        $server = Server::all();
        $guild = User::with('guilds')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

        return view('main.server.create', compact('categories', 'languages','users'));
    }
```

**StoreController**

```
        try{
            $data = $request->validated();
            $categoryIds = $data['category_ids'];
            unset($data['category_ids']);
            $data['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

            $server = Server::firstOrCreate($data);
            $server->categories()->attach($categoryIds);

        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            abort(404);
        }
```

When you selected the values in select. it is stored in the Server table under the title value

```
        Schema::create('servers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('content');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('invite');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('icon_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('language_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();

            $table->index('icon_id','server_icon_idx');
            $table->index('language_id','server_language_idx');
            $table->index('category_id','server_category_idx');

            $table->foreign('icon_id','server_icon_fk')->on('icons')->references('id');
            $table->foreign('language_id','server_language_fk')->on('languages')->references('id');
            $table->foreign('category_id','server_category_fk')->on('categories')->references('id');

            $table->timestamps();
         });
```

And the values that are output to select are taken from the UserGuild

```
        Schema::create('user_guilds', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('guild_id')->nullable();

            $table->index('user_id','user_guild_user_idx');
            $table->index('guild_id','user_guild_guild_idx');

            $table->foreign('user_id','user_guild_user_fk')->on('users')->references('id');
            $table->foreign('guild_id','user_guild_guild_fk')->on('guilds')->references('id');


            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
class UserGuild extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
    public function guild(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Guild::class);
    }
```

Comment: You can control this in invoke method. If the entry already available in server table don't send to your blade file

Comment: Basically **select** must show a list of all `Guild` except the guild already selected by the User previously - is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Donkarnash Yes that's right

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi  That's the problem, that I don't understand how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with such a terrible method, in `invoke` I added `$servers = Server::all();`

```
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    @foreach($user->guilds as $guild)
                             <option value="{{$guild->id}}"
                                 @foreach($servers as $server)
                                     @if($guild->id == $server->title)
                                        disabled
                                     @endif
                                 @endforeach
                             >{{$guild->name}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
           </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may pass all the `Guild` records from controller to the view

```php
public function __invoke()
{
    $user = User::with('guilds')->find(auth()->id());
    $categories = Category::all();
    $languages = Language::all();
    //$server = Server::all();
    $guilds = Guild::all();

    return view('main.server.create', compact('categories', 'languages','user', 'guilds'));
}
```

In the view you can filter out the records

```php
<select class="select-css" name="title" required="">
    <option selected="" value="" disabled="">Выберите сервер</option>
        @foreach($guilds as $guild)
            @if(!$user->guilds->contains('id', $guild->id)
                <option value="{{$guild->id}}">{{$guild->name}}</option>
            @endif
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Another option would be to filter out the `Guild` records within the controller itself

```php
public function __invoke()
{
    $user = User::with('guilds')->find(auth()->id());
    $categories = Category::all();
    $languages = Language::all();
    //$server = Server::all();
    $guilds = Guild::whereNotIn('id', $user->guilds->pluck('id')->toArray())->get();

    return view('main.server.create', compact('categories', 'languages','user', 'guilds'));
}
```

Then in view it's a normal `@foreach`

```php
<select class="select-css" name="title" required="">
    <option selected="" value="" disabled="">Выберите сервер</option>
        @foreach($guilds as $guild)
            <option value="{{$guild->id}}">{{$guild->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: I made the first option, and it outputs a void. The second option does not suit me, because I check in invoke **$guild** what data needs to be output. That's exactly why I attached the Model UserGuild

Comment: "First option outputs void" - do you mean that select options are not being populated? Check `dd($guilds, $user->guilds)` result in the controller just before the return statement. Does either of them returns empty collection ?

Comment: Yes, it's not filling up. My English is too bad.
 Outputs an error -**Property [guilds] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: Sorry my bad `$users` is a collection so you can try dumping `dd($guilds, $users->first()->guilds)` . Have also updated answer to take `$users` loop in account.

Comment: Outputs two collections. The first collection is the common database of all guilds. The second collection is the UserGuild database. I did as you just updated, but it still doesn't fill in :D

Comment: @foreach($users as $user)
                    @foreach($user->guilds as $guild)
I did so, and did as in your example

Comment: Yeah I see that its loop with a loop so it will show once for each user record. You know what, whatever the create form is for it must be specific to the currently logged in user right? Then you need to get just that user and not all users. Which would mean that you won't need to loop over the users in the view. In the `StoreController` you are attaching `user_id` to the data as id of currently logged in user so for data also you will need to pull out data for currently logged in user in the `CreateController` - let me update answer

Comment: In general, I wanted to later refuse to attach the user_id to the StoreController

Comment: You have a non nullable `user_id` column on `servers` table probably as FK to associate with `User` record so you will need to provide a value for it when storing the record to `servers` table. And since you are using `auth()->id()` it's for currently logged in user which is ok.